# Why $\overline{zw} = \overline z \ \overline w$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Suppose $z, w \in \mathbb C$. Using standard notation, prove that 
$$\overline{zw} = \bar z \bar w.$$

How would you solve this question?

Comment: Write $z=z_1+iz_2$, $w=w_1+iw_2$ and compute $zw$ then $\overline{zw}$. On the other hand, compute $\bar{z}$, $\bar{w}$ then $\bar{z}\bar{w}$.

Answer (score 6):

In complex analysis, the standard form of $z\in \mathbb{C}$ would be $z = a + bi$. So if you let $z = a + bi$, $w = c + di$, it's easy to compute: $$zw = ac + adi + cbi + bdi^{2} = ac + i(ad + cb) - bd = (ac - bd) +i(ad +cb)$$

If you now take the conjugate of $zw$, and the conjugate of $z$ and $w$, you can easily verify that $\overline{zw} = \bar{z} \bar{w}$.

Answer (score 4):

Both the RHS and the LHS can be seen as bilinear maps over $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since such identity holds for $z,w\in\{i,1\}$, it holds for any couple of complex numbers (two bilinear forms that agree over the couples of elements of a base are the same bilinear form).

Answer (score 0):

The deep reason: $i$ and $-i$ are both roots of $-1$ and can be interchanged in identities.

Answer (score 0):

If $z=r_ze^{i\theta_z}$ and $w=r_we^{i\theta_w}$ then $\bar z=r_ze^{-i\theta_z}$ and $\bar w=r_we^{-i\theta_w}$

so $zw= r_z r_w e^{i(\theta_z+\theta_w)}$ and thus $\overline{zw} = r_z r_w e^{-i(\theta_z+\theta_w)} = \bar z \bar w$.